# A warning in my ReactJS app - Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I have this pop-up form made with React-bootstrap components. I get this error on the console:

> Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here:
> in div (created by Modal)
> in Transition (created by Fade)
> in Fade (created by BackdropTransition)
> in BackdropTransition (created by Modal)
> in Modal (created by Modal)
> in Modal (at UpdateProfileForm.jsx:15)
> in UpdateProfileForm (at Profile.js:91)
> in div (created by Row)
> in Row (at Profile.js:86)
> in div (created by Card)
> in Card (at Profile.js:31)
> in div (created by Container)
> in Container (at Profile.js:30)
> in Profile (created by Context.Consumer)
> in Route (at App.js:31)
> in Switch (at App.js:24)
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter (at App.js:21)
> in App (at src/index.js:9)
> in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
> [image]
> but I really don't know how to solve it. Help

This is my pop-up form component.

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, Button, InputGroup, Form, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";

function CreateTeamForm(props) {
  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title
          id="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          style={{ fontSize: "30px" }}
        >
          CREATE TEAM
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <h4 style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>Team Information</h4>

        <InputGroup style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}>
          <InputGroup.Prepend>
            <InputGroup.Text>
              <i className="fas fa-users fa"></i>
            </InputGroup.Text>
          </InputGroup.Prepend>
          <FormControl id="Team Name" placeholder="Team Name" />
        </InputGroup>

        <InputGroup style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}>
          <InputGroup.Prepend>
            <InputGroup.Text>
              <i className="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </InputGroup.Text>
          </InputGroup.Prepend>
          <FormControl id="Members Emails" placeholder="Members Emails" />
        </InputGroup>
        <Form.Group controlId="Description">
          <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3" />
        </Form.Group>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={props.onHide} variant="light">
          Close
        </Button>
        <Button className="btn--primary" variant="primary">
          CREATE
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default CreateTeamForm;
```

Comment: Did you visit the url in the error message?

Comment: This is an issue with `react-bootstrap` and one of the packages it uses. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5075) about it